# Shopify scripttag install -> URI::BadURIError

Tags: javascript, heroku, shopify

I'd like to install a scripttag for shopify with a Rails App.
My js file is here: http://javascript.dataglobe.eu/index.js, it has only one sayHello() function. 
I made the authentication in my Rails app, I get the token, and I added two lines to install a  scripttag:

```
ShopifyAPI::Base.site = @token
s = ShopifyAPI::ScriptTag.create(:event => "onload",:src => "http://javascript.dataglobe.eu/index.js")
```

My app is deployed to heroku, and after installing it, I always get this error:
URI::BadURIError (both URI are relative):
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:19:in `index'

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're following the instructions for the gem, namely this part:

1. Use that token to instantiate a session that is ready to make calls to the given shop.

   token = params[:access_token]
   session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new("yourshopname.myshopify.com", token)
   session.valid?  # returns true

6.Now you can activate the session and you’re set:

```
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
```

From the docs for the gem here: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api

A good way to verify things are working is by request ion some data, such as products or orders and see if the request completes.

Comment: If this isn't the issues please post stack traces or the code from your controller so that we can figure out what is happening.

Comment: I tryed it, this is my controller:                                   sess = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(params['shop'],response['credentials']['token'])
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(sess)
ShopifyAPI::ScriptTag.create(:event => "onload",:src => "http://javascript.dataglobe.eu/index.js")  The Session is valid, I checked it. I got this error message: "Failed.  Response code = 403.  Response message = Forbidden." .... why is it forbidden?

Comment: Oh, I found the answer... that was because of the lack of write_script_tags scope....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bringing up an old post. But I found that if I put in my controller:

```
around_filter :shopify_session
```

It fixed many things for me. I was using the Shopify App they provided.